# Genetic algorithm final stage

Tags: c++, genetic-algorithm

I have written the code for a genetic algorithm and have the crossover function, mutation function, parent selector function and a function to transfer genes. Now I want to put it all together and would like to know if the following code is good programming practice or not.

```
Species Parents[popSize];
Species Children[popSize];

for(int gen = 0 ; gen < 100 ; gen++){
for(int i = 0; i < popSize ; i ++)
{
    int parentA = chooseParent(Parents);
    int parentB = chooseParent(Parents);
    crossOver(Parents[parentA] , Parent[ParentB] , Children[i]);
    Children[i].mutate();
}
for(int i = 0; i < popSize ; i ++)
{
    transfereGenes(Children[i], Parents[i]);
}
}
```

Comment: Using != for the end conditions, and pre-increment instead of post-increment is perhaps more idiomatic c++. Maybe don't hard code the 100 limit, and use a const variable. Perhaps use std::array instead of C-style arrays. Besides that there's not much here to actually comment on... it's just a few for loops.

Comment: You should probably include `crossOver` and `transfereGenes`

Comment: @user673679 you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Style

> ```
> Species Parents[popSize];
> Species Children[popSize];
> ```

It's more common for variables to start with lower case letters.

```
Species parents[popSize];
Species children[popSize];
```

That way you can easily tell that `Species` is a type while `parents` is a variable.  As it is, I have no way to tell why `Parents` is capitalized and `parentA`, etc. are not.

> ```
> for(int gen = 0 ; gen < 100 ; gen++){
> for(int i = 0; i < popSize ; i ++)
> {
> ```

You're mixing two styles here.  Both are valid, but it's generally preferred to pick one and use it consistently throughout your code.  More of the code is using `{` on a separate line, so it may be best to standardize on that.  Personally, I prefer it the other way, but as I said, both are valid.

```
for (int gen = 0; gen < 100; ++gen)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < popSize; ++i)
    {
```

Also, you indent inside the inner loops but not the outer.  It's unclear if this was intentional or a copy/paste error.  Note that if you indented the outer lines extra to make them appear in a code block, that it's often better to select the whole code and use Ctrl+K to indent them.  That will increase the indent of the entire code, not just the outermost lines.

I also changed the spacing to a more common form.

Preincrement may be defined more efficiently than postincrement.  It's a tiny difference, but some people prefer always using preincrement when either would work functionally.  Note that a compiler may compile out the difference entirely anyway.

### `<` versus `!=`

A comment argued that it is more common to use `!=` rather than `<`, but I think that they missed the point.  C++ favors using iterators in this situation.  Since many iterators don't have a meaningful `<` operator, they use something that looks sort of like

```
for (auto i = iterator.begin(); i != iterator.end(); iterator++)
```

However, that doesn't apply if your `for` loop is over an `int`.  Because `int` values do have meaningful `<`, these are more robust.  There's no need to maintain consistency at the price of robustness.  Consider

```
for (int i = 0; i != 5; i +=2)
```

This code will crash with an integer overflow (or loop forever) because `i` will never equal `5`.  And this code might otherwise be a sensible replacement for

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
```

Note that if you were using `std::array` or `std::vector` and C++11, you could use the new range-based `for` loop.

```
for (auto child : Children)
```

Then you don't have to manually manage your iteration at all.

### Missing code

You use `Parents[i]` but you never set it to anything.  Perhaps `chooseParent` or `crossOver` does that for you, but it's not clear.  It's also not clear why you `transfereGenes` (should that be transfer rather than transfere?) with `Children[i]` and `Parents[i]`.  Why are those two related now when they weren't earlier?

This is probably also a violation of the Single Responsibility Principle.  Initialization of the `Parents` and `Children` arrays presumably occurs somewhere.  But since it doesn't happen here or in a method called something like `initialization`, it's not obvious where.  Nor is it obviously correct.  We're essentially relying on the function implementations being correct.  But I don't even know what they are supposed to do.  I can guess a bit from the names, but this code won't work at all unless one of them handles initialization.

Is your code correct?  Without knowing what the code it calls does, I have no way of knowing.  If you want more of a review, you may want to post a new question with more context.  Preferably with runnable code.

> ```
>     crossOver(Parents[parentA] , Parent[ParentB] , Children[i]);
> ```

Is this a typo?  Should it be

```
    crossOver(Parents[parentA], Parents[ParentB], Children[i]);
```

I can't be sure.  Maybe the missing code has a `Parent` array as well.  And of course if not, a runnable version would find that trivially with a compile.